# Video don't play in Chrome (but play in Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video

I generated a direct link for a video.

```
https://dev-file.abrino.ir/public/download?id=181db12c3514fcc74518cbbe70a0c7cc6864c6e7.mp4&preview=true
```

When I open this link in Firefox, it's play correctly. But on Chrome not play.

What's problem?

Comment: what MIME type is your download handler returning?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, Did you mean Content-Type? I set it as "video/mp4"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/MIME_type looking at console log in Chrome it's not liking the document that's being returned so maybe compare all the headers you're sending to one that does work

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, Firefox headers are same as Chrome and I've set Content-type as "video/mp4"

Comment: there seem to be a few SO/SU posts about this issue, seems to point to a few different config things to check